# how to allocate the dynamic memory with our own function (without using malloc)

Tags: c

how to allocate the dynamic memory with our own function

without using malloc(), how to allocate dynamic memory using C language.

Comment: Why?  You would need to use your O/S's native memory APIs, which makes the code non-portable.

Comment: `malloc` is a standard c function . And why you don't want to use `malloc` ?

Comment: Maybe your assignment is to program a memory allocator, lying on top of `sbrk` system call?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `malloc`() provided by the library, you will have to implement your own memory manager, but I don't see any reason for doing so. That code is thoroughly tested and is in use for a long time. 
You can implement your own sample memory manager based on the `sbrk`() system call.
I would recommend you to go through the following link.

Assuming you are on linux, check the link below:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-memory/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get fresh heap memory without some support from the underlying operating system. I am assuming you have a POSIX operating system, e.g. Linux.

You could define your own `malloc`, but (in a hosted C implementation) most library functions assume that it has the traditional semantics (two successive and successful calls to `malloc` without any `free`-s producing two unaliased pointers to distinct non-overlapping memory zones).

In practice, your system `malloc` is generally implemented by querying fresh segments -in multiples of 4Kbytes pages- from virtual memory in your address space with a system call like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). But your standard C library `malloc` tries hard to reuse previously `free`-d memory zones before calling `mmap`, and it allocates some "large" (e.g. 128Kbytes or 1Mbytes) memory chunks using `mmap` and organize it as a set of memory zones (details are complex, since most `malloc` implementations are optimized for actual common use-cases). Quite often, `malloc` handles small allocations differently than large ones.
Occasionally (but most often not) a `malloc` implementation might release memory to the kernel using e.g. `munmap` but this does not happen often in practice. So in practice a process which has `malloc`-ed a lot of memory in many small zones and have `free`-d almost all of them still keep a lot of memory (to be able to reuse it without any `mmap`)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory.

That said, you could define global `char` array with a very large size and write a series of functions to hand out space from that array.  However, you need to keep track of what is/isn't available and be aware of alignments issues.  And that's just scraping the surface.

Bottom line: use `malloc`.