# Why deallocating heap memory is much slower than allocating it?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

This is an empirical assumption (that allocating is faster then de-allocating).

This is also **one** of the reason, i guess, why heap based storages (like *STL* containers or else) choose to not return currently unused memory to the system (that is why *shrink-to-fit* idiom was born).

And we shouldn't confuse, of course, '*heap*' memory with the '*heap*'-like data structures.

---

So **why de-allocation is slower**?

Is it *Windows*-specific (i see it on *Win 8.1*) or *OS* independent?

Is there some C++ specific memory manager automatically involved on using '*new*' / '*delete*' or the whole mem. management is completely relies on the OS? (i know *C++11* introduced some garbage-collection support, which i never used really, better relying on the old *stack* and *static* duration or self managed *containers* and *RAII*).

Also, in the code of the *FOLLY string* i saw using old C heap allocation / deallocation, is it faster then C++ '*new*' / '*delete*'?

---

**P. S.** please note that the question is **not** about *virtual memory* mechanics, i understand that *user-space* programs didn't use real mem. addresation.

Comment: Please post your real code.

Comment: Allocation/Deallocation are system calls, they have the kernel implementation that you can call with `syscall()`. All the allocation/deallocation functions declared in libs, like new / delete of c++ or malloc of c++, can extend the syscall or just call it. It will depends on the OS for the performances, because you can't rewrite the kernel implementation of the allocation at its root.

Comment: What is an emperical assumption?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant: No, allocation (`malloc` & `new`) and deallocation (`free` & `delete`) are *not* system calls (on Linux, listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)....).The C runtime (e.g. `malloc`) might *sometimes* call `mmap` or `sbrk` but not always (it tries to reuse previously `free`-d zones). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32332783/841108)

Comment: @AmaboCarab: are you sure of your initial claim? Did you code and benchmark a program which `malloc` many zones of random sizes and `free` them in some random order?

Comment: malloc/free handle some fairly complicated data structures so they can recycle memory and not cause too much fragmentation. It is a bit arbitrary and depends on the exact algorithms which parts of the bookkeeping are done during malloc and which parts during free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had much the same idea as @Basile: I wondered whether your base assumption was actually (even close to) correct. Since you tagged the question C++, I wrote a quick benchmark in C++ instead.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    using namespace std::chrono;
    using factor = microseconds;

    auto const size = 2000;

    std::vector<int *> allocs(size);

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        allocs[i] = new int[size];

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto alloc_time = duration_cast<factor>(stop - start).count();

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[] allocs[i];

    stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto del_time = duration_cast<factor>(stop - start).count();

    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << "alloc time: " << alloc_time << " uS\n";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << "del time: " << del_time << " uS\n";
}
```

I also used VC++ on Windows instead of gcc on Linux. The result wasn't much different though: freeing the memory took substantially less time than allocating it did. Here are the results from three successive runs.

```
alloc time:         2,381 uS
del time:           1,429 uS

alloc time:         2,764 uS
del time:           1,592 uS

alloc time:         2,492 uS
del time:           1,442 uS
```

I'd warn, however, allocation and freeing is handled (primarily) by the standard library, so this could be different between one standard library and another (even when using the same compiler). I'd also note that it wouldn't surprise me if this were to change somewhat in multi-threaded code. Although it's not actually correct, there appear to be a few authors who are under the mis-apprehension that freeing in a multithreaded environment requires locking a heap for exclusive access. This can be avoided, but the means to do so isn't necessarily immediately obvious.

Comment: Well, i took your code, compiled it with the _size = 2000_ in my _MS VS 2013 Commuinty Update 5_ with the speed optimization fully turned on AND on my _Windows 8.1 Lenovo IdeaPad S400_ i got **alloc time:         16 | del time: 109** (x100 000)

Comment: So yep, dealloc is 10 times slower in my case.

Comment: @AmaboCarab: I'm not at all sure that's actually true. It could be--but it's known that in VS 2013, the implementation of `high_resolution_clock` is quite thoroughly broken. If you really care about results with this compiler, you'll probably want to rewrite the test to use a different timer (e.g., `GetPerformanceCounter`) instead.

Comment: **Jerry Coffin**, yes, it is true that the clock is a bit broken, i know it, OK, i will compile the code uisng _MS VS 2015 Update 2_, but i don't think i will have a completly diffirent results.

Comment: @AmaboCarab: That said, I'm not able to reproduce anything even close to your results--although I don't entirely trust them, the results I get with VS 2013 follow roughly the same pattern I see with other compilers: deletion being *around* twice as fast as allocation.

Comment: **Jerry Coffin**, i fully turned the speed optimization, may be that case? I am almost sure the comipler options set is the key.

Comment: Well OK, same code same project same machine etc all is the same, but MS _VS 2015 Community Update 2_ i got **alloc time: 2 127 917 | del time:           1 537 209**, so YEP here it is allmost same.

Comment: @AmaboCarab: I've been using `/O2b2 /GL` as the compiler options. I've tried various others, but haven't been able to find any that give results like you're citing. I find it hard to believe it'd make much difference--most of what we're timing is code in the standard library, so about all the matters is which library gets linked.

Answer (score 3):

The assertion that allocating memory is faster than deallocating it seemed a bit odd to me, so I tested it. I ran a test where I allocated 64MB of memory in 32-byte chunks (so 2M calls to `new`), and I tried deleting that memory in the same order it was allocated, and in a random order. I found that linear-order deallocation was about 3% *faster* than allocation, and that random deallocation was about 10% *slower* than linear allocation.

I then ran a test where I started with 64MB of allocated memory, and then 2M times either allocated new memory or deleted existing memory (at random). Here, I found that deallocation was about 4.3% slower than allocation.

So, it turns out you were correct - deallocation is slower than allocation (though I wouldn't call it "much" slower). I *suspect* this has simply to do with more random accesses, but I have no evidence for this other than that the linear deallocation was faster.

To answer some of your questions:

*Is there some C++ specific memory manager automatically involved on using 'new' / 'delete'?*

Yes. The OS has system calls which allocate pages of memory (typically 4KB chunks) to processes. It's the process' job to divide up those pages into objects. Try looking up the "GNU Memory Allocator."

*I saw using old C heap allocation / deallocation, is it faster then C++ 'new' / 'delete'?*

Most C++ `new`/`delete` implementations just call `malloc` and `free` under the hood. This is not required by the standard, however, so it's a good idea to always use the same allocation and deallocation function on any particular object.

I ran my tests with the native testing framework provided in Visual Studio 2015, on a Windows 10 64-bit machine (The tests were also 64-bit). Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace AllocationSpeedTest
{       
    class Obj32 {
        uint64_t a;
        uint64_t b;
        uint64_t c;
        uint64_t d;
    };
    constexpr int len = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
    Obj32* ptrs[len];
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(Linear32Alloc)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Linear32AllocDealloc)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                delete ptrs[i];
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Random32AllocShuffle)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                int pos = (rand() % (len - i)) + i;
                Obj32* temp = ptrs[i];
                ptrs[i] = ptrs[pos];
                ptrs[pos] = temp;
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Random32AllocShuffleDealloc)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                int pos = (rand() % (len - i)) + i;
                Obj32* temp = ptrs[i];
                ptrs[i] = ptrs[pos];
                ptrs[pos] = temp;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                delete ptrs[i];
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Mixed32Both)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (rand() % 2) {
                    ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
                }
                else {
                    delete ptrs[i];
                }
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Mixed32Alloc)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (rand() % 2) {
                    ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
                }
                else {
                    //delete ptrs[i];
                }
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Mixed32Dealloc)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (rand() % 2) {
                    //ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
                }
                else {
                    delete ptrs[i];
                }
            }
        }
        TEST_METHOD(Mixed32Neither)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
            }
            srand(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (rand() % 2) {
                    //ptrs[i] = new Obj32();
                }
                else {
                    //delete ptrs[i];
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here are the raw results over several runs. All numbers are in milliseconds.
[image: Table of raw results]

Comment: This is very interesting, as the _Basile Starynkevitch_ example on his GCC & Debian results in "**free seems to be twice as fast as malloc**".

Comment: In my example I did take care to allocate some rather random sizes and the free in a random order.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of your observation. I wrote the following program (on Linux, hopefully you could port it to your system).

```
// public domain code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>


const unsigned possible_word_sizes[] = {
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
  8, 12, 16, 24,
  32, 48, 64, 128,
  256, 384, 2048
};

long long totalsize;

// return a calloc-ed array of nbchunks malloced zones of
// somehow random size
void **
malloc_chunks (int nbchunks)
{
  const int nbsizes =
    (int) (sizeof (possible_word_sizes)
       / sizeof (possible_word_sizes[0]));
  void **ad = calloc (nbchunks, sizeof (void *));
  if (!ad)
    {
      perror ("calloc chunks");
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
  for (int ix = 0; ix < nbchunks; ix++)
    {
      unsigned sizindex = random () % nbsizes;
      unsigned size = possible_word_sizes[sizindex];
      void *zon = malloc (size * sizeof (void *));
      if (!zon)
    {
      fprintf (stderr,
           "malloc#%d (%d words) failed (total %lld) %s\n",
           ix, size, totalsize, strerror (errno));
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      ((int *) zon)[0] = ix;
      totalsize += size;
      ad[ix] = zon;
    }
  return ad;
}

void
free_chunks (void **chks, int nbchunks)
{
// first, free the two thirds of chunks in random order
  for (int i = 0; 3 * i < 2 * nbchunks; i++)
    {
      int pix = random () % nbchunks;
      if (chks[pix])
    {
      free (chks[pix]);
      chks[pix] = NULL;
    }
    }
// then, free the rest in reverse order
  for (int i = nbchunks - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (chks[i])
      {
    free (chks[i]);
    chks[i] = NULL;
      }
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  assert (sizeof (int) <= sizeof (void *));
  int nbchunks = (argc > 1) ? atoi (argv[1]) : 32768;
  if (nbchunks < 128)
    nbchunks = 128;
  srandom (time (NULL));
  printf ("nbchunks=%d\n", nbchunks);
  void **chks = malloc_chunks (nbchunks);
  clock_t clomall = clock ();
  printf ("clomall=%ld totalsize=%lld words\n",
      (long) clomall, totalsize);
  free_chunks (chks, nbchunks);
  clock_t clofree = clock ();
  printf ("clofree=%ld\n", (long) clofree);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -O2 -Wall mf.c -o mf` on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 (i3770k, 16Gb). I run `time ./mf 100000` and got:

```
nbchunks=100000
clomall=54162 totalsize=19115681 words
clofree=83895
./mf 100000  0.02s user 0.06s system 95% cpu 0.089 total
```

on my system `clock` gives CPU microseconds. If the call to `random` is negligible (and I don't know if it is) w.r.t. `malloc` & `free` time, I tend to disagree with your observations. `free` seems to be twice as fast as `malloc`. My `gcc` is 6.1, my `libc` is Glibc 2.22.

Please take time to compile the above benchmark on your system and report the timings.

FWIW, I took [Jerry's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38031606/841108) and

```
 g++ -O3 -march=native jerry.cc -o jerry
 time ./jerry;  time ./jerry; time ./jerry
```

gives

```
alloc time:         1940516
del time:           602203
./jerry  0.00s user 0.01s system 68% cpu 0.016 total
alloc time:         1893057
del time:           558399
./jerry  0.00s user 0.01s system 68% cpu 0.014 total
alloc time:         1818884
del time:           527618
./jerry  0.00s user 0.01s system 70% cpu 0.014 total
```

Comment: In fact, i saw the above described dehaviour (i. e. deallocating heap memory is much slower than allocating it) with the C++ program, which used the STL container (it was a hash map or set), which is filled and destroyed then. One point to mention: i guess that this behaviour is observed when the application heap was already heavely used/fragmented. It might be critical, as all there performs their tests on a fresh execution. I also use Windows, not *nix, that is important too. I see that test presented here gives vary diffrent results, so i gues the answer is actually depends.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate small memory blocks, the block size you specify maps directly to a suballocator for that size, which is commonly represented as a "slab" of memory containing same size records, to avoid memory fragmentation.  This can be very fast, similar to an array access.  But freeing such blocks is not so straight forward, because you are passing a pointer to memory of unknown size, requiring additional work to determine what slab it belongs to, before the block can be returned to its proper place.

When you allocate large blocks of virtual memory, a memory page range is set up in your process space without actually mapping any physical memory to it, and that requires very little work to accomplish.  But freeing such large blocks can require much more work, because the pointer freed must first be matched to the page tables for that range, followed by walking through all of the page entries for the memory range that it spans, and releasing all of the physical memory pages assigned to that range by the intervening page faults.

Of course, the details of this will vary depending on the implementation being used, but the principles remain much the same:  memory allocation of a known block size requires less effort than releasing a pointer to a memory block of unknown size.  My knowledge of this comes directly from my experience developing high-performance commercial grade RAII memory allocators.

I should also point out that since every heap allocation has a matching and corresponding release, this pair of operations represents a single allocation cycle, i.e. as the two sides of one coin.  Together, their execution time can be accurately measured, but separately such measurement is difficult to pin down, as it varies widely depending on block size, previous activity across similar sizes, caching and other operational considerations.  But in the end, allocate/free differences may not much matter, since you don't do one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is heap fragmentation. Programs written in languages with explicit pointer arithmetic have no realistic ways of defragmenting heap.

If your heap is fragmented, you can't return memory to OS. OS, barring virtual memory, depends on `brk(2)`-like mechanism - i.e. you set an upper bound for all memory addresses you'll refer to. But when you have even one buffer allocated and still in use near existing boundary, you can't return memory to OS explicitly. Doesn't matter if 99% of all the memory in your program is freed.

Dealocation doesn't have to be slower than allocation. But the fact that you have manual deallocation with heap fragmenting makes allocation slower and more complex.

GCs fight this by compactifying heap. This way, allocation is just incrementing pointer for them, and deallocation is not needed for bulk of objects.

Comment: You assmues that NO memory ever returns to the OS unless the process is terminated? Or i understand you wrong? Thats really strange, what whith the long running server programs? Sytem resources, like sockets? Thats seems like one big memory leak then...

Comment: @AmaboCarab system resources used by programs are usually structures in OS memory, referred by opaque numeric "handles" or "fds". OS does good job allocating and reusing them. Now, programs don't return memory to OS but they can reuse memory. If they happen to free memory at the same pace as they alocate it, they'll not run out of memory.

Comment: you mean that the program heap is always a privite heap? And some specific process fragemts only it's own heap, NOT the main generic heap? And this private heap can ONLY grow in time, never shrink? So the OS manages this heap, NOT the runtime library or it is unkonwn, not specified and implementation-based?

Comment: This answer doesn't really seem to provide any explanation why deallocating would be slower. In fact, if the program isn't releasing the memory, it should be *faster* because of fewer system calls.

Comment: Modern allocators use `mmap()` most of the time instead of `brk()` which is much better to fight fragmentation.

Comment: @gudok If you allocate large buffers - maybe. If you allocate zillion tiny buffers, don't think `mmap()` will help.